# Apache localhost/~username/ Forbidden

Tags: macos, apache, terminal, localhost

I am currently trying to get my apache webserver local host working so I can work on php websites on my own computer. I am running mac OSX 10.11.2.

I have tried every resource from every link I can find containing the same problem. I can access local host but when i try to access localhost/~username I get a 403 Forbidden error! Says I do not have permission. I have uncommented out all of the lines that I am told to do but I can not get it to work.

Any help is much appreciated

I can't figure out how to post my config, but I assure you I have uncommented everything I need to

Comment: Have you set permissions on the ~username folder?  You need to have at least execute permission (in some cases) and read permission.

Comment: How did you setup Apache web server? You should specify the way or the resource link you used to setup it; for example installing XAMPP, installing MAMP, using OS X internal Apache web server, compiling the source code of it, installing with package managers, ...